# Spacemacs user-config error

Tags: spacemacs, major-mode, emacs25

I'm using **Spacemacs** to develop a laravel + Vue application and I followed the steps in [this configuration example](https://medium.com/@aria_39488/improving-vue-mode-for-better-vue-js-editing-inside-of-spacemacs-4509f0577ea0) to highlight syntax in Vue, but now every time **Spacemacs** starts it gives me this **error**:

---

> (Spacemacs) Error in dotspacemacs/user-config: Symbol’s function definition is void: lsp-make-traverser.

This is my **dotspacemacs-user-config()**:

*EDIT 1: Only the vue-mode example config.*

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()

  (require 'vue-mode)
  (add-to-list 'vue-mode-hook #'smartparens-mode)

  (require 'lsp-mode)
  (require 'lsp-vue)
  (add-hook 'vue-mode-hook #'lsp-vue-mmm-enable)
  (with-eval-after-load 'lsp-mode
    (require 'lsp-flycheck))

  (require 'company-lsp)
  (push 'company-lsp company-backends))
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.10

Emacs: GNU Emacs 25.2.2

Spacemacs: 0.200.13

Here is my [dotspacemacs](https://pastebin.com/1KXzEu4t)

Comment: Please narrow the code you show down to just what is needed to raise the error.

Comment: I don't know much about lisp so i don't know what's causing the error, anyway, I've posted a copy of my whole config file. @Drew

Comment: I found an open issue that seems  to be what you are running into.  There's a solution in the conversation you might find helpful https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-vue/issues/20